# C Program - Getting "Segmentation Fault" when trying to read from a file

Tags: c

Please bear with me since I'm still new in programming. I'm trying to read a file and store its context as a variable, here's my code I'm sorry if it's rather long:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

// CEK ROUTER MODEL
char* router_model;
char* model() {
    char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
    char* key = "system type";
    char* value;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[1000];

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            //fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
            if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
                char* value = strchr(line, ':');
                value += 2;
                router_model = strdup(value);
                break;   // once the key has been found we can stop reading
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }
    return router_model;
}

// TULIS SERIAL NUMBER KE FILE
char tulis(char p[100]) {
    // Write a serial number to a file
    char sn[30];
    char encrypt_sn[50];
    printf("Serial Number:\n");
    scanf("%s", sn);
    FILE *f = fopen("/usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(f,"Serial Number: %s", sn);
    fclose(f);
    sprintf(encrypt_sn, "ccrypt -e /usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c -K %s", p);
    system(encrypt_sn);
    system("mv /usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c.cpt /usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c");
    printf("Serial number is saved in /usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c\n");
    return 0;
}

// BACA SERIAL NUMBER & SIMPAN DALAM SEBUAH VARIABLE
char baca(char p[100]) {
    // Store the serial number from a file in a variable
    char line[50];
    char decrypt_sn[50];
    char key[30] = "Serial Number";
    char *serial_number;
    if( access( "/usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c", F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        system("cp /usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c /tmp/");
        system("mv /tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c /tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c.cpt");
        sprintf(decrypt_sn, "ccrypt -d /tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c.cpt -K %s", p);
        system(decrypt_sn);
        FILE *file = fopen("/tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c", "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
            //fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
            if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
                char* value = strchr(line, ':');
                value += 2;
                serial_number = strdup(value);
                break;   // once the key has been found we can stop reading
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        //printf("Your hardware serial number is: (%s)\n", serial_number);
        remove("/tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c");
    }
    else {
        printf("fsn not found\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *r;
    char *del;
    char *decrypt;
    int ret;
    char input[30];
    char *p;
    char *original_sn;
    p = "MmI4MTUxM2FjMjRlMDkzYmRkZGQyMjcwMjQ4OWY3MDAwNGZiYTM0MWNkZGIxNTdlYzAxN2";
    //tulis(p);
    original_sn = baca(p);
    printf("SN: %s", original_sn);
    return 0;
}
```

The file I'm trying to read is `/usr/share/terminfo/f/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c` and after being decrypted with `ccrypt`, the content of that file is `Serial Number: 1866203214226041`. I want to store `1866203214226041` as a variable but I'm getting `Segmentation Fault` when running that code, how do I fix it ?

Comment: `ccrypt -d /tmp/fsn-55cfc8770b69cc07268fae7f25ee444c.cpt -K %s` alone is too long for `decrypt_sn`, you are overflowing your buffers. **Don't use `sprintf`, use `snprintf` instead.** And large enough buffer sizes.

Comment: `encrypt_sn` is small too.

Comment: Also, using `scanf("%s", sn);` is as bad as using `gets`; you have no protection for receiving too large strings. Use max width limit on `scanf`, or use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @user694733 thanks for the buffer tips, the `Segmentation Fault` is gone now but I'm getting `SN: (null)` now, how do I fix it?

Comment: You might want to cover the case that `strchr(line, ':')` returns `NULL`; as it stands now, it would very likely crash the program.

Comment: We prefer only one question at the time here on SO. I recommend that you use debugger to monitor your variables, while you step through  the program. Then ask new question if you cannot solve that problem.

Comment: @user694733 okay I'll make another post then, thank you for your help

Comment: @user694733 I tried creating another topic but stackoverflow limits my post to one every 90 minutes, can you just please help me here ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to do extensive debugging right now, nor is it a scope of this site. You should really start to use debugger, it's a skill that is essential to solving programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this snippet extracted from your code:

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
        //fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
        if (strncmp(line, key, strlen(key)) == 0) {
            char* value = strchr(line, ':');
            value += 2;
            router_model = strdup(value);
            break;   // once the key has been found we can stop reading
        }
    }
```

First of all, you don't check the value returned from `strchr(line, ':');` as you will get `NULL` in case the string begins with `system type` but doesn't have a `':'` char on it.  You assume it will always find a `':'` and **increment** the value by two (if it doesn't find the char, it will generate a pointer into position `2` of page zero of mem (which normally implies a `SIGSEGV` signal on later access from `strdup(3)` call).  Also, after incrementing by `2`, you can just skip the last `\0` character, if the `':'` character happens to be the last of the line.

## Note

A final comment.  As it is true that having `key` initialized at top makes the `while` loop more efficient, calling `strlen(key)` inside the loop makes the code to find the end of the string pointed to by `key` at each loop iteration, to get the string length.  Better to precalculate `strlen(key)` outside the loop (as it is constant) and use that value on the `if` statement, like this:

```
    size_t key_length = strlen(key);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
        //fprintf(stdout, "%s", line); //print the file contents on stdout.
        if (strncmp(line, key, key_length) == 0) {
            char* value = strchr(line, ':');
            if (value) { // only if value is != NULL should we continue
                value += 1; // we are not sure if after ':' we'll have a null char `\0` so better do a +1 increment.
                router_model = strdup(value);
                break;   // once the key has been found we can stop reading
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thing is: Don't use a so short string array for `encrypt_sn`(only 50 chars space for a max 49 length null terminated string) when you are printing that so large strings (I think only the format is already longer than that [edit] around 75 chars [/edit]) as you are running in a buffer overflow with your own code.  This can be another source for `SIGSEGV`.

No more checks have been done to your code, but ther can be more.  I think the same problem happens with `decrypt_sn` later on.

One more question:  Why do you tag your source as `_BSD_SOURCE` if it is not bsd source anymore? (no `procfs` in bsd systems, no `/proc/cpuinfo` in bsd systems)  I've tried to check my debian amd64 system's `/proc/cpuinfo` file and no `system type` field found there.